# How to play gif in qt cpp?

Tags: c++, qt, qmovie

I want to show a gif on the screen until an action is finished.
As far as I understand from the examples, I tried something like this, but the gif does not appear on the screen. How can I do that?

```
QMovie *movie=new QMovie(":/images/loading.gif");
    if (!movie->isValid())
        {
         qDebug()<<"Movie is not valid";
        }

    // Play GIF
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);

    label->setMovie(movie);
    movie->start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an event loop.  Bracket your code with a `QApplication` creation and `exec`...

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QMovie movie(":/images/loading.gif");
if (!movie.isValid()) {
    qDebug() << "Movie is not valid";
}

// Play GIF
QLabel label;

label.setMovie(&movie);
movie.start();
app.exec();
```